# How can I cycle through elements that don't have display:none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of elements (li's) that some of them may or may not be invisible through a '.hide()'. How can I select only the visible elements?

Basically I have a text field that when the user clicks or focuses on it a list of possible options appears, the user can either type somethign in and the options shrink as they are filtered accordingly or else the user can use the up and down arrows to scroll through the available options. when an option becomes unavailable it is 'hidden' through a '.hide()'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

```
$('li:visible').doSomething()
```

Comment: can the ':visible' selector be applied to a '.prev()' and a '.next()'?

Comment: @WilliamCalleja if you meant like `prev('selector:visible')`, yes.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved big part of my problem but at this point I think that it has evovled to warrant a different question

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a [selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) especially for this case.

```
$('li:visible').each(function(x,y){...});
```

Comment: can the ':visible' selector be applied to a '.prev()' and a '.next()'?